# Refresh a main window from a popup window

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

Here is my problem. In my web application which has developed using JSP/servelt there is a page with an link. When some one click that link a popup window by calling a javascript function as follows.

> function addlist() {
>    winArray[7] =
>   window.open("Changelist.jsp","changeList","status=1,resizable=0,width=290,height=370");
>
> }

That popup window allow user to add things to the main window. What I want to do is when user add a new thing main window should get updated. There is already a update ajax function in the main window. What I need to do is when user add new thing to list I need to call the update method in the main window. how can I do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your popup window, your JavaScript code may have a reference to the main window thanks to the [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener) property. You could thus call `window.opener.update()` when the new thing has been added.